# how to swipe item in recyclerview when using contentproviders

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-contentprovider, swipe

I want to swipe item from recyclerview and when item is swiped the bottom item should move up.

in onCreateView of my Fragment

```
 new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0,
                ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
            @Override
            public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"ByBy",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                myListCursorAdapter.onItemRemove(viewHolder, recyclerView);
            }
        }).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

in Adapter

```
public class TaskCursorAdapter extends RecyclerCursorAdapter<TaskCursorAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    Context context;
    Cursor cursor;


    public TaskCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super(context, cursor);
        this.cursor = cursor;
        this.context = context;
        setHasStableIds(true);

    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public TextView taskname;
        public TextView dateDetails;
        Context context;
        Cursor cursor;

        public ViewHolder(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
            super(view);
            this.context = context;
            this.cursor = cursor;
            taskname = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listitemtaskname);
            dateDetails = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listitemdatedetails);
            view.setOnClickListener(this);
        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // Form the content URI that represents the specific pet that was clicked on,
            // by appending the "id" (passed as input to this method) onto the
            // {@link PetEntry#CONTENT_URI}.
            // For example, the URI would be "content://com.example.android.pets/pets/2"
            // if the pet with ID 2 was clicked on.
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, EditorActivity.class);
            Uri currentPetUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(TaskContract.TaskEntry.CONTENT_URI, this.getAdapterPosition() + 1);

            intent.setData(currentPetUri);
            context.startActivity(intent);


        }
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view, context, cursor);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, Cursor cursor) {

        int taskColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(TaskContract.TaskEntry.NAME);
        int dateColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(TaskContract.TaskEntry.DUEDATE);
        int timeColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(TaskContract.TaskEntry.DUETIME);

        String task = cursor.getString(taskColumnIndex);
        String dateString = cursor.getString(dateColumnIndex);
        String timeString = cursor.getString(timeColumnIndex);

        viewHolder.cursor = cursor;
        viewHolder.taskname.setText(task);

        if (timeString == null && dateString == null) {
            viewHolder.dateDetails.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        } else {
            viewHolder.dateDetails.setText(dateString + "\t\t" + timeString);
        }

    }

    public void onItemRemove(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        int adapterPosition = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()+1;
         Uri currentPetUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(TaskContract.TaskEntry.CONTENT_URI, viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());


        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                .make(recyclerView, "PHOTO REMOVED", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("UNDO", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        int mAdapterPosition = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition() + 1;
                        Toast.makeText(context,"Hi",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        recyclerView.scrollToPosition(mAdapterPosition);

                    }
                });
        snackbar.show();
        context.getContentResolver().insert(TaskContract.TaskEntry.CONTENT_URI_FINISHED, values);
       // Toast.makeText(context,"Hi2",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //notifyItemChanged(adapterPosition);
        recyclerView.scrollToPosition(adapterPosition);


    }

}
```

I tried everything but its difficult to swipe item from recyclerview and when undo of snackbar is pressed i want that item to reappear.I want to swipe item from recyclerview and when item is swiped the bottom item should move up.

Answer (score 2):

1) You need to override the method onSwiped() as below.

```
ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleItemTouchCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN | ItemTouchHelper.UP) {

            @Override
            public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
               //do something
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int swipeDir) {      
                int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
                arrayList.remove(position);//remove swiped item
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();//notify the recyclerview changes in the dataset

            }
     };

ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleItemTouchCallback);
itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(rv);//attach to your recyclerview
```

2) Don't forget to import v22.2.+ of the RecyclerView library.

3) For the botom item to move up(update) you need to do a refresh after "adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()" first update the database then pull the new data from the database(with changes).  This will update the database and also the recyclerview.

4) To Undo you need to keep a stack of the elements that were removed(LIFO order) and insert them back as you click undo.

Comment: Please check my question, ihave already overided the method and i cant use arraylist as i am using sqlite with content provider

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Content Provider you must call your cursor inside onSwiped method like this:

```
 ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleItemTouchCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(
            0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {

        @Override
        public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int swipeDir) {      
            final int position = viewHolder.getLayoutPosition();
            Cursor cursor = myListCursorAdapter.getCursor();
            cursor.moveToPosition(x);
                final long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(Your_Column_ID));
                getActivity().getContentResolver().delete(Uri.withAppendedPath(YourContract.YOUR_URI, String.valueOf(id)), null, null);
            }
 };
ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleItemTouchCallback);
itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(yourRecyclerView);          //attach to your recyclerview
```

In your Adapter you must set getCursor():

```
   public Cursor getCursor(){
    return yourCursor;
  }
```